# Process Google Bookmarks Feed in SimplePie

Tags: php, simplepie, google-books

I want to process my Google Bookmarks feed using SimplePie.

I can access a feed at https://www.google.com/bookmarks/find?q=&output=rss&num=10000

But I obviously will need to be logged in for that to work, so can I pass SimplePie some already authenticated cookies?

Or is there another way to access the Bookmarks?  Don't know why there still isn't an official API :(

Answer (score 0):

The Google bookmarks feed uses basic auth, so you should be able to access the feed with simplepie using your username and password in the url:

https://username:password@www.google.com/bookmarks/find?q=&output=rss&num=10000

If you use an gmail address as username, you can omit "@gmail.com" from your username.